# Best way to check if an index is "out of bounds"

Tags: c

If I have the following statement that runs in a loop:

```
rows[row_num++] = row;
```

What would be the best way to check if the index of the current `rows` array is within the array length or not? i.e., to prevent a seg fault.

Comment: How do you think you would do it?

Comment: C doesn't come with any inherent object count, that part is the responsibility of the programmer. Save a count of the total number of elements, then `while (row_num < total) rows[row_num++] = row;`. If, *and only if*, you are dealing with an array *within the scope it was declared*, then `sizeof rows / sizeof *rows` will provide the total number or rows available. However, if the array is passed as a function argument, then it is converted to a pointer and that no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the size of the array in runtime like this

```
array_size = sizeof(rows)/sizeof(rows[0]);
```

Comment: Only sometimes.